# Google cloud sql read replica consistency

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

Does Google Cloud SQL read replicas guarantees consistency? And how long does it take to replicate from primary to read replicas typically? I can't find information on the above two questions.

Answer (score 0):

From this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/replication#read-replicas), the read replica is an exact copy of the primary instance. Data and other changes on the primary instance are updated in almost real time in normal circumstances on the read replica. By default, a replica starts with replication enabled. You [connect](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-admin-ip) to a replica directly using its connection name and IP address. If you're connecting to a replica using a private IP address, you don't need to create an additional VPC private connection for the replica as it is inherited from the primary instance. However, you cannot stop the replica, you can enable replica, delete the replica, promote the replica or disable the replica (does not stop the replica instance; it becomes a read-only instance that is no longer replicating from its primary instance).

When you view a replica instance using the Google Cloud Console or log into the instance using an administration client, you get [details about replication](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replication-administration-status.html), including status and metrics. The following metrics are available for replica instances :

- Replication State
- Replication Lag
- Slave I/O thread running state
- Slave SQL thread running state
- Seconds_behind_master : The amount of time, in seconds, by which the
  replica lags in processing the primary's transactions, i.e. the
  difference between (1) the current time and (2) the original
  timestamp at which the primary committed the transaction that is
  currently being applied on the replica. The value is NULL if
  replication is broken.

When you use the gcloud command-line tool, you get a brief summary of the replication configuration. Cloud SQL reports the Replication State and Replication Lag metrics on the [default Cloud SQL monitoring dashboard](https://console.cloud.google.com/monitoring/dashboards/resourceList/cloudsql_database?_ga=2.214893076.284218699.1634628354-44778869.1624531808). For more information refer to the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/replication/manage-replicas#replication-status).

Also if you are trying to create read replicas on the primary instance and facing issues like :

- Read replica did not start replicating on creation.
- Unable to create a read replica - invalidFlagValue error.
- Unable to create a read replica - unknown error.
- The replica instance is using too much memory.
- Replication stopped.
- Replication lag is consistently high (The time that it takes a
  replica to catch up to the master)
- Replication creation fails with timeout.

For above scenarios, have a look at the troubleshooting steps and also understand why these issues occur as listed in [Google Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/replication/create-replica#troubleshooting).

Note : Read replicas do not provide failover capability. So we have to [configure our instance for high availability](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/configure-ha). As a best practice, put read replicas in a different zone than the primary instance when you use HA on your primary instance. This practice ensures that read replicas continue to operate when the zone that contains the primary instance has an outage.